# How to alter role from command line in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, sh

I'm trying to build a setup script to automate the development environments creation, but I'm having trouble both trying to pipe or using the -c modifier for psql.

I've tried:

```
sudo su postgres psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres WITH password 'pass'"
```

and

```
sudo su postgres psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres WITH password 'pass';"
```

Both of which say "ALTER: command not found"

I've also tried pipe, but I'm not able to combine it with su correctly

eg: I tried something like

```
sudo su postgres echo "ALTER ROLE postgres WITH password 'pass'" | psql
```

But postgres can't execute "echo"

And:

```
echo "ALTER ROLE postgres WITH password 'pass'" | sudo su psql
```

Which just doesn't work.

So, my first question is: how can I execute this simple command from a sh file?

And the second one, less related: how can I use different users in the commands chained with pipe?

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` or `su`? Can't you just start `psql -U postgres` directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What's wrong is the lack of `-c` or `--command` for `su` to indicate that the rest of the line is a command.

But `su` is not needed anyway, because there's already `sudo`. Do this instead:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres WITH password 'pass'"
```

Comment: Perfect. This is the way to go

Comment: Then i get `could not change directory to "/home/ubuntu": Permission denied`

Comment: @Soren: this is normal if the permissions of `/home/ubuntu` don't allow  `postgres` to go into it. You may use `sudo -Hiu postgres` to avoid that message.

Comment: Ok, so the command actually works, it just also creates the error message because it cannot change to that directory. That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just like me, make sure you are not running this from:

`bash-4.2$`

but:

`postgres=#`